# Is there a limit for Meliodas's full counter?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the last Nanatsu no Taizai movie, we see Tristan, Meliodas's son, can do the full counter, but it's limited to 3 or 4 attacks. Then Meliodas arrives, and he full counters thousands of attacks.

Is there a limit for Meliodas's full counter?